# Lambda to toggle between Console.Writeline(s) and Log,Info(s)

Tags: c#, lambda, log4net

C# I'm using the following lambda:  `s=> Console.Writeline(s)`
but I want to be able to switch between that and `s => this.Log.Info(s)`
dependent on the `Environment.UserInteractive` So it allows the switch between Console and logger dependent on where it is being invoked.  I thought I could have used a lambda statement but I'm getting all sorts of errors.

I'm trying `s => Environment.UserInteractive != true ? this.Log.Info(s) : Console.Writeline(s)`

This is used to pass the logger to an instance creation:  Here's the class:

```
public ABCStub(Action<string> logger);`
```

Comment: Go ahead, post the errors.

Comment: more code please. how is it being used?

Comment: I posted what I thought would work but this throws syntax erros

Comment: Would dependency injection be in scope? Where ILog could be injected perhaps...?

Comment: Share more codes please, so that we can see what is injected. And also would be useful to share syntax errors you are getting.

Comment: A ternary expression is not the same as an if..else statement; it must evaluate to a value, but both methods are void.

Comment: It seems like you should be using `logger` no matter what, and configure it to write to the console in an interactive context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
s => Environment.UserInteractive != true ? this.Log.Info(s) : Console.Writeline(s)
```

You should try

```
Environment.UserInteractive != true ? this.Log.Info : (Action<string>)Console.Writeline
```

This will solve the problem of ternary expressions on vois methods and also avoid evaluating the UserInteractive property on every call

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator to create the `ABCStub` with the correct action:

```
var abcStub =
    Environment.UserInteractive
    ? new ABCStub(Log.Info)
    : new ABCStub(Console.Writeline);
```

A ternary operator cannot simply be used in place of an if..else statement; it must return a value.